# Efficiently storing data in assembly and computing with it

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

recently i started learning assembly and it is quite a journey! :) I know a few basic things and I wanted to learn about data storage by recreating my python program. The program should take an input (I am not sure if it is possible in asembly) and return the number of heads a hydra will have after a certain number of days. Formula:`result = ((old_day*new_day)+(new_day-old_day))`
I have simplified my python code to:

```
old_day = 2
new_day = 3
fight = 5

temp1 = 0
temp2 = 0
temp3 = 0

for i in range(fight):
    temp1 = old_day*new_day
    temp2 = new_day-old_day
    temp3 = temp1+temp2
    old_day = new_day
    new_day = temp3

print(old_day)
```

And so far I came up with this in assembly:

```
global _start

section .data
    old dw 2
    l_old equ $ - old
    new dw 3
    l_new equ $ - new
    tem1 dw 0
    l_tem1 equ $ - tem1
    tem2 dw 0
    l_tem2 equ $ - tem2
    tem3 dw 0
    l_tem3 equ $ - tem3
    days dw 4


section .text
_start:
    mov al, [old]
    mov bl, [new]
    mov cl, [tem1]
    mov dl, [tem2]
    mov ah, [days]

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

label:
```

I got stuck at the label since `mul` stores its result in `aex` but i store my values in `al` and `ah`.
My question is: Will the `mul` override my data? Is there a better way of storing data? And finally do I need all the lines with `equ` or is that only relevant when outputting?
Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: Pick different registers for your data, or use `imul reg, reg` if you don't need the high-half result in EDX.  Look at how compilers implement C functions to get examples: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: Your Python code is wrong. It uses `old_day` before it's assigned.

Comment: added the old_day back